# How can I disable the network detection on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have a computer running Windows 7 that shares some files on the network. This works fine for a while until for some unknown reason the computer decides that it is connected to a new, unknown public network and disables the file sharing capabilites.

Nothing physically changes with the computer, it is still connected to the same network via ethernet cable. But it does misidentify the network every other day, just plugging out the ethernet cable and putting it back in leads Windows to correctly identify the work network and enabling the share again.

Is there some way to stop Windows from trying to identify the network automatically, and just tell it that the network on that computer will never change?

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, you can tell Win7 (and Vista) to not query what type of network, but to assume it's "Home, Public, whatever".

Last I saw, it was a checkbox in the lower part of the "Choose a network type" window.  Maybe locking it to a particular type would help.

Don't have a windows machine here at the moment to poke around, so that's from memory...

Answer (score 0):

If your system runs Bonjour try to uninstall it.

Also try.

Type `Cmd` in the Start Search text box. Now instead of hitting the Enter key
press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` keyboard shortcut to run a  Command Prompt as an Administrator.

Allow elevation.

- Type   `route delete 0.0.0.0`    press enter.
- Type   `ipconfig /flushdns`     press enter.
- Restart.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the run dialog (Windows)+r:

type services.msc + (return)

Disable the "Network List Service"

Reboot.

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Just to let you know - the correct thing to do with duplicate questions is to flag (or when you have more reputation)or to vote to close as duplicate.